# Pycharm - Setting up a Username and Password login script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have the below code which just repeats the username and password request on the pycharm client. Can you see why I am receiving the infinite loop?

Comment: I think the infinite loop is due to not returning from "while True"

Comment: Python is all about indentations.your `with` statement is already outside of the loop. I am guessing you want everything to be indented under the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:

    username = input("Enter your Username ")
    password = input("Enter your Password ")
```

I mean you have an infinite while loop right here. You don't even need one here right?

Comment: Its probably because you're calling mysql.connect instead of mysql.connector.connect